# Error while building spring boot project

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, spring-boot

i am unable to build my springboot project, 
I am using classes from another springboot jar, which i placed on the build path, its running in local via eclipse, but is not building, here's the error

```
"[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ContentManagementService 0.0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ contentmanagementapi ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/bhargavgundu/git/contentmanagementservice/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ contentmanagementapi ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 5 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ contentmanagementapi ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 42 source files to /home/bhargavgundu/git/contentmanagementservice/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/bhargavgundu/git/contentmanagementservice/src/main/java/com/conduiraonline/controller/ContentManagementControllerV1.java:[32,31] package com.conduiraonline.apis does not exist
[ERROR] /home/bhargavgundu/git/contentmanagementservice/src/main/java/com/conduiraonline/controller/ContentManagementControllerV1.java:[42,31] package com.conduiraonline.daos does not exist
[ERROR] /home/bhargavgundu/git/contentmanagementservice/src/main/java/com/conduiraonline/controller/ContentManagementControllerV1.java:[52,35] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SlackService
  location: package com.conduiraonline.services
[ERROR] /home/bhargavgundu/git/contentmanagementservice/src/main/java/com/conduiraonline/controller/ContentManagementControllerV1.java:[85,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class UserDAO
  location: class com.conduiraonline.controller.ContentManagementControllerV1
[ERROR] /home/bhargavgundu/git/contentmanagementservice/src/main/java/com/conduiraonline/controller/ContentManagementControllerV1.java:[87,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SlackService
  location: class com.conduiraonline.controller.ContentManagementControllerV1
[ERROR] /home/bhargavgundu/git/contentmanagementservice/src/main/java/com/conduiraonline/controller/ContentManagementControllerV1.java:[95,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class LicenseV5
  location: class com.conduiraonline.controller.ContentManagementControllerV1
[INFO] 6 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.917s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Sep 12 17:16:44 IST 2017
[INFO] Final Memory: 24M/396M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project contentmanagementapi: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/bhargavgundu/git/contentmanagementservice/src/main/java/com/conduiraonline/controller/ContentManagementControllerV1.java:[32,31] package com.conduiraonline.apis does not exist
[ERROR] /home/bhargavgundu/git/contentmanagementservice/src/main/java/com/conduiraonline/controller/ContentManagementControllerV1.java:[42,31] package com.conduiraonline.daos does not exist
[ERROR] /home/bhargavgundu/git/contentmanagementservice/src/main/java/com/conduiraonline/controller/ContentManagementControllerV1.java:[52,35] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class SlackService
[ERROR] location: package com.conduiraonline.services
[ERROR] /home/bhargavgundu/git/contentmanagementservice/src/main/java/com/conduiraonline/controller/ContentManagementControllerV1.java:[85,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class UserDAO
[ERROR] location: class com.conduiraonline.controller.ContentManagementControllerV1
[ERROR] /home/bhargavgundu/git/contentmanagementservice/src/main/java/com/conduiraonline/controller/ContentManagementControllerV1.java:[87,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class SlackService
[ERROR] location: class com.conduiraonline.controller.ContentManagementControllerV1
[ERROR] /home/bhargavgundu/git/contentmanagementservice/src/main/java/com/conduiraonline/controller/ContentManagementControllerV1.java:[95,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class LicenseV5
[ERROR] location: class com.conduiraonline.controller.ContentManagementControllerV1
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
"
```

It is showing errors wherever i am using classes/functions from the external jar, can someone help?
MY POM-

here is my POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.conduiraonline</groupId>
    <artifactId>contentmanagementapi</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>ContentManagementService</name>
    <description>ContentManagementService</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.conduiraonline</groupId>
            <artifactId>licenseapi</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
            <classifier>exec</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>21.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Compile time errors, check whether the necessary JAR files are included and do the JAR files added suffice?

Comment: you need to add the maven dependency of your external jar in your pom

Comment: @cralfaro i did add it, check the lines having "licenseapi"

Comment: add <scope>compile</scope>

Comment: Whenever you want add jar to your project add it as dependency in your project instead of adding it in build path, because maven won't recognize the build path jars, if the dependency is not available in repositories create maven dependency script https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project and run it on classpath level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Remove `<classifier>exec</classifier>` from the dependency on `com.conduiraonline:licenseapi`

**More Details ...**

You are correct in using `<dependency>` to express the relationship between `com.conduiraonline:contentmanagementapi` and `com.conduiraonline:licenseapi`. Or to put it another way; this is the *right* way to tell Maven that the module `com.conduiraonline:contentmanagementapi` depends on the module `com.conduiraonline:licenseapi`.

However, you have defined the dependency on `com.conduiraonline:licenseapi` as:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.conduiraonline</groupId>
        <artifactId>licenseapi</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
        <classifier>exec</classifier>
    </dependency>
```

The `classifier` tells Maven to look for an file named `licenseapi.exec` in the folder `com/conduiraonline` in your local Maven repo (and failing that, try to resolve that dependency from whatever remote repositories you have configured in your Maven settings.xml or in this pom.xml).

I presume there is no file named `licenseapi.exec` in the folder `com/conduiraonline` in your local Maven repo because `exec` is a very unusual classifier for a Maven artifact.

As long as a JAR for `com.conduiraonline:licenseapi` with version `0.0.1` has been installed in your local Maven repo this dependency will work:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.conduiraonline</groupId>
        <artifactId>licenseapi</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

You install a JAR for `com.conduiraonline:licenseapi` with version `0.0.1` in your local Maven repo by running `mvn clean install` for the `licenseapi` module (assuming that the pom.xml for the `licenseapi` modules has `<version>0.0.1</version>`).

Comment: This worked, Thanks :) i have one doubt, once i do this, that jar need not be present on the class path also right?

Comment: By declaring that dependency you are telling Maven that `com.conduiraonline:contentmanagementapi` has a compile dependency on `com.conduiraonline:licenseapi`. I'm not fully sure what you mean by "that jar need not be present on the class path" but by declaring that dependency you are saying that you **do** expect that JAR to be present on the classapth.

Answer (score 0):

You must add the path of your jars / folder containing jars in your gradle or maven build file.

For example in gradle add

```
    compile fileTree(dir: 'path_to_ext_libs', include: '*.jar')
```

to your dependencies in the build.gradle then all the jars in the libs folder will be then included.

or in maven

```
<repositories>
   <repository>
     <id>local-files</id>
     <name>local-files</name>
     <url>file://c:\test\filerepo</url>
  </repository>
```

Comment: can you tell how to do that in maven? isn't it the same as adding in POM?

Comment: I added the jar from build path and it appears in 'Referenced libraries', that should work right?

Comment: Either trust gradle or maven or trust your IDE .